# Is there a way to get the text height (point perfect not approximate ) for a UITextview in iOS7 (for a chat cell in tableview ) with constant width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview

`UITextview` has a padding of 8 points on each side. Hence I pass 16 points less to the width of the CGRect- height of which I want to find. 
As it can be seen in the below function(using `sizeWithFont`), for iOS6, I get point perfect height. 
But for iOS7, the height I get is not accurate when I use the function (using `boundingRectWithSize`).

```
#pragma mark - Private methods

- (CGFloat)getTextHeight{
    if (isSentMessgae) {
        return [_chatMessageModel.message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_TT size:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(194, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    }
    return [_chatMessageModel.message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_TT size:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(154, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;

}

- (CGFloat)getTextHeightIOS7{

    if (isSentMessgae) {
        NSString *text = _chatMessageModel.message;
        CGFloat width =154;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_TT size:16];
        if (isSentMessgae) {
            width =194;
        }
        NSAttributedString *attributedText =
        [[NSAttributedString alloc]
         initWithString:text
         attributes:@
         {
         NSFontAttributeName: font
         }];
        CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                   context:nil];
        DebugLog("text heigh : %f",rect.size.height);
        return (rect.size.height);
    }


    NSString *text = _chatMessageModel.message;
    CGFloat width =154;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_TT size:16];
    if (isSentMessgae) {
        width =194;
    }
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:text
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: font
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    // DebugLog("text heigh : %f",rect.size.height);
    return (rect.size.height ));
}
```

Comment: did you try getting the points of the font you're using ?

Comment: #define FONT_TT @"HelveticaNeue"
I am using the above font. Sorry, by pixels in the question I meant points. As mentioned in the question, the height I get for iOS6 is point perfect but not for iOS7. 
Thanks

Comment: I have this same issue, using sizeWithFont and boundingRectWithSize in iOS7 is giving an inaccurate height, when my label text has multiple white spaces in a row. The word wrapping behaviour in iOS7 is different to iOS6. Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: No not yet
Have not come across a function for this in iOS7 which is accurate for all cases